# How to forbid automatic databinding on validation error

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I'm creating a simple database application in C# WPF using MVVM as Relay Commands and databinding. For in-memory storage of database content I use `ObservableCollection`, which is binded to the Datagrid as follows:

`<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Softwares, Mode=OneWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SoftwareSelection, Mode=TwoWay}">`

when the item is selected user can chose to edit it. For editation a form is opened with a bunch of textboxes with the data of given entity. All the fields are validated using `IDataErrorInfo`, unless all textboxes are valid, the ok button is not enabled, and therefore no changes can be saved to the collection and to the database.

Here is how the example textbox looks like:

`<TextBox Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>`

But the tricky part is, in case I change some values in textboxes and then close the window, the new values are propagated to the `ObservableCollection`, which I don't want to. Do you have any idea, how to prevent such behaviour? I would like the databinding work only after clicking the button. Otherwise the databindng works well, so as the button (dis/en)abling and reflecting changes to the database and to the collection after clicking. Both views are serviced by different ViewModels, data between views are passed by firing events.

I tried to add to the `DataGrid` `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit` to the ItemsSource binding, but didn't help. Perhaps, I'm missing some application logic?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is where most WPF developers make mistakes of assumptions!

In MVVM dirty data can be stored in the `ViewModel` and that's what the layer of VM is for! It mimics the `View` from `Model`'s perspective and because `View` is in error, the `ViewModel` would also be in the error. Thats perfectly valid.

So having said that, the question remains

> How will you NOT allow the **temporary** / **dirty** data to flow to your
>   ObservableCollection?

Two ways...

1. If your `ObservableCollection` is specific to your model class (say `MyItem`) then if your Model class (`MyItem`) is an Entity class \ DAL class \ NHibernate class create a wrapper of `MyItem` class called `ViewModelMyItem` and then instead of `ObservableCollection<MyItem>` use `ObservableCollection<ViewModelMyItem>`.

   This way dirty data from your `View` would be inside `ViewModelMyItem` and it can only be legitimately flown back to your model class (`MyItem`) ONLY when `Save` button is clicked. So that means in `Save Command`'s `Execute()` delegate you can copy \ clone the `ViewModelMyItem`'s properties into `Item`'s properties, if validations in `ViewModelMyItem` are fine.

   So if `Item` is an `EntityType` class / `NHibernate` class / `WCF` client model class, it would always only valid data as `ViewModelMyItem` is filtering the temporary / dirty information upfront.
2. You could use `Explicit` binding model. It stops the `TwoWay` data to flow back to the sorce `Item` unless `BindingExpressions.UpdateSource()` is explicitly called.

   But according to me, this defeats MVVM in straightforward way because `ViewModel` will not have what UI is showing! Still however you can use **Attached Behavior ** to govern explicit binding by staying in MVVM space!

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You're better off putting the code into the domain object's property setter. Then synchronize with the visuals by triggering the `NotifyPropertyChanged` handler.

More on this topic: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx

Comment: Well, this is what I actualy do, the ViewModel with the datagrid contains collection of Software entities. and the viewmodel for edition contains a single Software entity, whose properties are filled as follows: `        public string Name {
            get { return software.Name; }
            set {
                if (software.Name != value) {
                    software.Name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Name");}}
        }` otherwise I dont understand what do you mean. :(

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Binding Mode to Explicit should require you to call the binding expressions UpdateSource() method to send changes back to your model.  Because you only mentioned that you set Explicit on the DataGrid's binding, I'm guessing you only need to make sure that you have that mode explicitly set on any property that is being bound directly back to your model.  Such as your TextBox's Text Binding, in the case above.  That will likely fix your problem but require you to call UpdateSource() on each target's BindingExpression one way or another.

If you're using one of the mainstream ORM's (EF, Linq to SQL, etc), then chances are your Entities automatically implement INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyPropertyChanging.  Because you are sharing a reference to your single instance, all changes in your edit will be reflected in your main view and anything else Binding to that instance.  As a dirtier alternative, you can just create a separate instance of the same type and manually copy the values back over when the window's dialog result is true.

The first approach requires you to manually update the bindings, the second approach requires you to manually update the values from the Edit's instance.

With some more code, I can help with your specific approach.